# Yodlee getSiteLoginForm API response changes between attempts

Tags: yodlee

There seems to be an inconsistency with the responses for Yodlee's **getSiteLoginForm** REST API function.

For a site that has a login field with radio buttons, sometimes the data coming back from Yodlee for that particular field will look like this:

```
{
    "fieldInfoList": [
        {
            "validValues": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4"
            ],
            "displayValidValues": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4"
            ],
            "valueIdentifier": "OPTIONS",
            "valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD",
            "fieldType": {
               "typeName": "OPTIONS"
            },
            "size": 20,
            "maxlength": 40,
            "name": "OPTIONS",
            "displayName": "Issue Number",
            "isEditable": true,
            "isOptional": false,
            "isEscaped": false,
            "helpText": "76367",
            "isOptionalMFA": false,
            "isMFA": false
        }
    ]
}
```

and other times it looks like this:

```
{
    "validValues": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4"
    ],
    "displayValidValues": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4"
    ],
    "valueIdentifier": "OPTION",
    "valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD",
    "fieldType": {
       "typeName": "OPTIONS"
    },
    "size": 20,
    "maxlength": 40,
    "name": "OPTION",
    "displayName": "Issue Number",
    "isEditable": true,
    "isOptional": false,
    "isEscaped": false,
    "helpText": "76367",
    "isOptionalMFA": false,
    "isMFA": false
}
```

It's the same field but the **valueIdentifier** value has changed and the data isn't being enclosed in a **fieldInfoList** variable. 
What would be the reason for this response data-set changing between two attempts if there's no difference in the code?

In addition to that, could a similar response inconsistency be affecting other API functions from Yodlee, and if so how does one deal with this uncertain variance?

Comment: Could you please provide the Site name or SiteId you used for this?

Answer (score 0):

We did analysis and Yodlee provides every time same response, no matter how many attempts you'll do. While I am assuming that you might be confused between getSiteLoginForm and getLoginFomForContentService, as both are two different APIs and belongs to approach i.e., Site Based and Container Based respectively. And the response you have mentioned first comes when you use getSiteLoginForm while the later one comes with getLoginFormForContentService.

Hope this helps as there is no issue with the API, these are two different response from 2 different APIs.